# call_user_func() : cannot access private method

Tags: php

This code does not work:

```
class A {
    public function b() {
        (new B)->d([$this, 'c']); // Error is here
    }
    private function c() {
        echo 'test';
    }
}

class B {
    public function d($e) {
        call_user_func($e);
    }
}

(new A)->b();
```

Running this code gives:

> call_user_func() [...] cannot access private method A::c()

I can understand why it does not work. But I don't know the real reason. In `A::b()`, I'm in `A` context, that's why I thought `c()` can be called (`$this` is well known and *do* refers to `A`, so I'm in `A` context).

What is really weird for me is that it works if I replace:

```
(new B)->d([$this, 'c']);
```

By:

```
(new B)->d(function() { $this->c(); });
```

So it's not a problem to call a private function now. I can't understand why. And I did not found anything in doc about this.

Why `(new B)->d(function() { $this->c(); });` works but not `(new B)->d([$this, 'c']);` when I call `(new A)->b();`?

Comment: The closure version works like that (php feature, did you notice that you access $this in a fucntion without given it as arg, wont work with local variables, so it is special case here). And the other version takes it as args, so you are leaving the current scope.

Comment: If you want to go deep , read https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures/object-extension

Comment: Well, in the case of closure you're invoking `A::c()` right away in class `A` and therefore you have access to the private method. In the other case you're passing `$this` to `B::d` which in turn tries to call the private method `c()` of class `A`, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `[$this, 'c']` an **array** is passed with index `[0]` as reference of object of class A and index `[1]` as a string c, so it tries to call the function from method `d` using string stored in array index `[1]`.

When you pass the function directly a [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) is passed which is binded to class `A` so it can be used to call function `c` as it is binded to class `A`.

**However** you can use the first method too and not get any error by a little trick like this :

```
class A {
    public function b() {
        (new B)->d([$this, 'c']);// NO ERROR NOW!
    }
    private function c() {
        echo 'test';
    }
}

class B {
    public function d($e) {     
        // Here is the trick :          
        $f = function() { $this->c(); };
        $f = Closure::bind($f, $e[0], 'A');                 
        $f();
    }
}

(new A)->b();
```

What I did was create a closure and then bind using [::bind](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php) it to class A using the object reference received in `$e[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say if you use:

```
$this->c();
```

it gets executed right there, so from the class A, which has this function. 
if you do it like:

```
[$this, 'c']
```

you pass the class and the function that should be executed by class B, and it will also be executed by class B, but class B cannot access the private function of class A.

Regards